# How can I edit the ReSharper code cleanup profile without a license?

Tags: resharper

I am trying to use ReSharper's [CleanupCode Command-Line Tool﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/CleanupCode.html), which I believe can be used without a ReSharper license. That command-line tool accepts a `--profile` option. However, I can't figure out how to create a new profile.

[The documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Cleanup__Index.html#custom_profile) says to use the ReSharper Options dialog in Visual Studio. But I can't seem to edit the profile on that window, presumably because I don't have an active Visual Studio license.

How can I create a new code cleanup profile without a ReSharper license? I assume this profile must be stored as a file somewhere. Is that file editable as text? Where are these files stored? Can anyone share a sample file?

(For context, I want to run the CleanupCode tool for a specific rule, which I think requires me to create a custom profile.)

Comment: Editing an `.editorconfig` file in a root folter is not an option? resharper supports but not requires it. And you can use any editor

Comment: I got a license and found a settings file here: `C:\Users\srk\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\Shared\vAny\GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings`. Custom profiles are embedded in this file as XML. For example: `<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeCleanup/Profiles/=test_002Dprofile/@EntryIndexedValue">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;&lt;Profile name="test-profile"&gt;&lt;XAMLCollapseEmptyTags&gt;False&lt;/XAMLCollapseEmptyTags&gt;&lt;CSReformatCode&gt;True&lt;/CSReformatCode&gt;&lt;CSOptimizeUsings&gt;&lt;/CSOptimizeUsings&gt;&lt;/Profile&gt;</s:String>`.